# Game Engine to use with Eclipse for API 14

Tags: android, eclipse

Can anyone give a Game Engine that can be:

1. Used with Eclipse
2. Used for Android 4.0 or API level 14

I downloaded AndEngine But it is for API 15...Changed 8 to 15 in `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>` of AndEngine. Still it is saying android-15 cannot be found.

What can i do?

Comment: Did you update your Eclipse by using SDK manager?

Comment: @Tobor No my net is too slow to download

Comment: @Tobor any game engines to use with eclipse

Comment: If so, you can forget targetting it. Target a lower API level version, instead.

Comment: @Tobor i asked for API 14 which is there in my  SDK. I asked a game engine for that.

Answer (score 2):

I guess API lvl 15 is missing in your Android SDK. Try to update your SDK version and install API Level 15 SDK by using Android SDK Manager.

Comment: @Harikrishnan if you dont want to update your SDK, at least you can download only API 15 lvl package, it will be faster than updating the whole SDK. After you installed package, just restart Eclipse and use Project -> Clean.

Comment: Yes i need that can u give that link

Comment: @There is no direct link for different API level packages, you must use SDK manager in Eclipse to download specific API packages.

Comment: My SDK does not show API 15

Comment: If you can't find SDK manager in eclipse, you can launch SDK manager from the SDK location. To find SDK location press Window -> Preferences -> Android. After that go to that location and launch "SDK manager" exe file. I hope this will help

Comment: @Harikrishnan what level API's are available in your SDK?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45201/discussion-between-hari-krishnan-and-arshak92)